# Wishlist items are showing correctly in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

wishlist column from All_Collections have PK of Wishlist.But this below code pointing to the user id instead Wishlist PK(id).

```py
products = All_Collections.objects.filter(wishlist= request.user.id)
```

in this line facing issue
Can anyone please help me to solve this.

View.py

```
@login_required
def wish_list_add(request,id):

   item = get_object_or_404(All_Collections,id=id)
   wished_item,created = Wishlist.objects.get_or_create(product_id=item, user = request.user.id)
   messages.info(request,'The item was added to your wishlist')
   return redirect('all_collections')
@login_required
def wish_list(request):
    data = All_Collections.objects.filter()
    print("All Collections(product table)  : ", data.values('wishlist'))
    data = Wishlist.objects.filter()
    print("Wishlist PK            : " ,data.values('id'))
    data1=Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).values_list('id', flat=True)
    print("Wishlist pk values    :" ,data1)
    user_id = Wishlist.objects.filter(user = request.user.id)
    print('wishlist user         :' ,user_id)
    products = All_Collections.objects.filter(wishlist= request.user.id)
    print('Wishlist Items       : ',products)
    return render(request=request, template_name="D_Crown/wishlist.html",context={'wishlist': products})
@login_required
def wish_list_remove(request,id):

    item = get_object_or_404(Wishlist,id=id)
    Wishlist.delete(item.id)
    return redirect('wish_list')
```

Model.py

```
class All_Collections(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images')
    collection_desc = models.TextField()
    material_details = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    shape = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    review = models.IntegerField()
    no_purchases = models.IntegerField()
    offer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    offer_percentage = models.IntegerField()
    new_price = models.IntegerField()
    exchange = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    items_left = models.IntegerField()
    delivery_info = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.d_crown_all_collection

class Wishlist(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(All_Collections, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

output:

```
    Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
    All Collections(product table)  :  <QuerySet [{'wishlist': 4}, {'wishlist': 5}]>
    Wishlist PK            :  <QuerySet [{'id': 4}, {'id': 5}]>
    Wishlist pk values    : <QuerySet [4, 5]>
    wishlist user         : <QuerySet [<Wishlist: DCrown>, <Wishlist: DCrown>]>
    Wishlist Items       :  <QuerySet []>
    [04/Jul/2021 15:10:44] "GET /wish_list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5736
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access wishlist -> user in your filter which you can do with

```py
products = All_Collections.objects.filter(wishlist_set__user=request.user)
```

Since wishlist is a reversed foreign key, it'll be accessible as `wishlist_set` or you can give a `related_field` attribute to the field in the model initialization to give it a different name if you want.
the double underscores `__` lets you access inner fields.

Comment: Thankyou,....I changed the code the way you said--> products = All_Collections.objects.filter(wishlist__user=request.user) .Its working now